# Rails EOF Error when using HTTP.get_response to retrieve Facebook access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

I trying to implement a Login with Facebook feature on my site, and hitting a roadblock trying to get the access token back from Facebook. Here is my code:

```
if params[:error_reason] == "user_denied" then
  flash[:error] = "To login with Facebook, you must click 'Allow' to let the site access your information"
  redirect_to :login
elsif params[:code] then
  token_uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=****************&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/fblogin&client_secret=***************&code="+URI.escape(params[:code]))
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(token_uri)
  session[:response] = response
  data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
  access_token = data[:access_token]
  flash[:error] = access_token
  redirect_to :register
end
```

This is inside a `fblogin` controller function that is the target of the initial redirect to get an authorization code (the `params[:code]`).

But when I run through this, I get the following error:

`EOFError in AuthController#fblogin`

on the `Net::HTTP.get_response(token_uri)` line. I've searched all over, and can't find anything to indicate what this means. Could it be the obscure characters Facebook uses in their access tokens? I'm totally lost!

Comment: Is this Ruby 1.9? If so, you must manually configure a CRT file containing trusted CA certs, see http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are receiving an `EOFError` because you are trying to connect to an `https` URL using code that only works with `http`. See the section entitled "SSL/HTTPS request" at [this Net::HTTP Cheat Sheet](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) for the basics.

However, I would recommend using a third-party library to manage this for you, such as [OAuth2](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth2) for utilizing Facebook's OAuth2 API, where you'd write code like this:

```
def client
  OAuth2::Client.new('app_id', 'app_secret', :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com')
end

# in your callback code:
access_token = client.web_server.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/auth/fblogin')
user = JSON.parse(access_token.get('/me'))
```

If you really want to make the requests yourself, you can look at libraries like [Faraday](https://rubygems.org/gems/faraday) to execute the HTTPS requests for you.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer! I was attempting to write the requests myself to better understand the authentication flow (this is just a learning project). But I'll give OAuth2 a closer look!